# Must special characters in bash double quoted or escaped with \

Tags: bash

Should I double quote or escape with `\` special characters like `'`,

```
$ echo "'"
'
$ echo \'
'
```

Here is apparently doesn't matter, but are there situations where there is a difference, except for `$`, ``` `` or ````, when I know there is a difference.

Thanks,

Eric J.

Comment: Both are legal. There's no rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either backslashes, single quotes, or (on occasion) double quotes.

Single quotes suppress the replacement of environment variables, and all special character expansions. However, a single quote character cannot be inside single quotes -- even when preceded by a backslash. You can include double quotes:

```
$ echo -e 'The variable is called "$FOO".'
The variable is called "$FOO".
```

Double quotes hide the glob expansion characters from the shell (`*` and `?`), but it will interpolate shell variables. If you use `echo -e` or set `shopt -s xpg_echo`, the double quotes will allow the interpolation of backslash-escaped character sequences such as `\a`, and `\t`. To escape those, you have to backslash-escape the backslash:

```
$ echo -e "The \\t character sequence represents a tab character."
The \t character sequence represents a tab character."
```

The backslash character will prevent the expansion of special characters including double quotes and the `$` sign:

```
$ echo -e "The variable is called \"\$FOO\"."
The variable is called "$FOO".
```

So, which one to choose? Which everyone looks the best. For example, in the preceding `echo` command, I would have been better off using single quotes and that way I wouldn't have the confusing array of backslashes one right after another.

On the other hand:

```
$ echo -e "The value of \$FOO is '$FOO'."
The value of FOO is 'bar'.
```

is probably better than trying something like this:

```
$ echo -e 'The value of $FOO is '"'$FOO'."
```

Readability should be the key.